# Why would the Schmitt trigger relaxation oscillator a bit unstable?

Tags: oscillator, stability

This thing oscillates from time to time. Why? (Respect part numbers, all chips from NXP)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSrlmJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

`C14` = `74HC14D` (no Schmitt trigger symbol in Circuit Lab), `C06` = `74LVC1G06`.

The 10uF cap is a 1206 SMT tantalum I recycled from a dead board.

All SMT parts mounted on adapter boards and entire circuit is powered from USB, with another scrapped 10uF tantalum as filter cap and a (also scrapped) polyfuse. No bypass cap used.

-- **EDIT** --

Added bypass caps per Spehro Pefhany's suggestion, still does not work. However by replacing the long USB lead with a Li-ion battery pack it worked. Why?

-- **EDIT 2** --

Here is a picture of the actual set up. Li-ion pack shown and working, but with USB it does not work properly.

[image]

The big blue cap is a 4700uF aluminum electrolytic, the yellow square caps on boards are the 10uF tantalums, and the small leaded yellow caps are 100nF ceramic. The big chip is `74HC14`, and the smaller one, sharing an adapter board with the LED, is `74LVC1G06`. I am still using that buffer. The board strapped onto the Li-ion is charger/controller board, can be safely ignored.

Comment: Why you have cascaded three Schmitt triggers? Is not it enough just one?

Comment: One Schmitt trigger, no oscillation; three of them, some unstable oscillation. Essentially I wired two of them into a buffer.

Comment: IMO 20 kom R1 does not need a buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Data sheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT14.pdf) oscillation frequency is 5Hz, not 2Hz (K~=1).

A bypass capacitor is **not** optional especially when you're drawing so much current through the LED (a long USB lead will act like a transmission line). Try 100nF in parallel with 100uF electrolytic, and go back to the original circuit with one gate.

It's probably squegging all over the place without a bypass cap- but as you have no oscilloscope that would be hard to see.

Comment: Added bypass caps, now it works even less stable. :/

Comment: Tried powering it from a Li-Ion battery pack. Worked stably. Why Li-ion works but a long USB lead does not work, even with 1000uF input filter cap and 100nF at power rail of every chip?

Comment: It should not make much difference if you actually have the capacitors correctly connected (which I have to doubt, sorry).

Comment: Uploaded a pic of the set up.

Comment: There's a huge loop there across the power. Try moving the supply to one side of the breadboard and put the cap across those rails. Or, better, add 100n right on the chip breakout.

Comment: I do have 100uF at every chip breakout's power pin. However even with this and shifting all 4 input filter caps (4700uF aluminum, 470uF aluminum, 10uF tantalum and 100nF ceramic) next to the blob it is still not stable.

Comment: And here is the weird bit: I changed R2 from 100 ohm to 1k and powered the entire thing using a 1117-3.3 regulator, and now it is working fairly stable, even with only the 100nF ceramic and 10uF tantalum filter caps on the 3.3V rail. Why?

Answer (score 1):

It oscillates because it is configured as an oscillator.  By the look of R1 & C1, the period is pretty slow.

Comment: What I see is the frequency being unstable (instead of ~2Hz from the datasheet, I am getting all frequencies) and from time to time it stops oscillating.